# Openlayers-6 .fit(extent, {options}) not working with options

Tags: openlayers

I have upgrade Openlayers in IONIC V3 app from 4.6.5 to 6.1.0. Now `map.getView().fit(extent, {duration:1000})` stop working, when I remove the options object it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or anything else is needed?

```js
var extent;
extent = s_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
map.getView().fit(extent);
//this works fine.

map.getView().fit(extent, {duration: 1000});
//Doesn't fit the extent,just a slight movement on map.
```

I want to achieve a slight animation on map, when fit the extent of feature. Also tried `animate()` method of view class but not able to get the desired results.

Comment: I use it so: `var view = new ol.View({ ... }); map.setView(view); view.fit(extent, {duration: 1000});´ and it works by me with v6.1.0. And the options `size: map.getSize()`, "padding" and "maxZoom" works also. But with `map.getView().fit()` it works by me also.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I ended up using `.animate()` and had to remove `setZoom()` because that is one of the functions that will stop the animation.

```
if (text == currentManhole) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    //map.getView().fit(geometry);
    map.getView().animate({ center: geometry }, { duration: 750 });
    //map.getView().setZoom(currentZoom);                    
}
```

[OpenLayers animate()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#animate)